# ¿Consultas en firebase a través de childs de nivel más bajo?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, sql, kotlin

estoy haciendo una aplicación para gestionar asignaturas y tengo mi base de datos en Firebase Realtime. El esquema que tengo es:

```
|
-- Users
   |
    -- (key de users)
       |
       -- name
       |
       -- lastname
       |
       -- subjects
          |
          -- key1 : value1
          |
          -- key2 : value2
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que dada una clave de una asignatura (key1, por ejemplo) obtenga qué user o users tienen esa clase  en su propiedad **subjects**; o lo que es lo mismo, saber si un usuario está apuntado a una asignatura.

El problema es que con las *query* no sé recorrer los usuarios sin tener que traérmelos todos y recorrerlos con un *for in* en la aplicación.

¿Alguien sabría cómo puedo hacer la consulta? En la docu de Firebase no me queda muy claro porque soy muy novato.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo que tenes con el for in ?

Answer (score 0):

Es una base de datos NoSQL. La redundancia es buena.

Crea en paralelo una lista de Key de las asignaturas y los User inscritos.

```
|
-- Users
   |
    -- (key de users)
       |
       -- name
       |
       -- lastname
       |
       -- subjects
          |
          -- key1 : value1
          |
          -- key2 : value2
--Keys
   |
   --Key1
      |
      --User1
      |
      --User2

   --Key2
      |
      --User1
```